# Redirect Magento2 404 page to the register page

Tags: magento, redirect, registration, custom-fields

I'm using Magento 2 to create my site. I want to dynamically assign a sponsor to the register of a new customer. I had create a customer custom field named nickname on the database. In practice I want to provide a link such as http://mywebsite.net/John1 where John1 is the nickname of the sponsor. The system will give an error not finding the requested page. I want to edit 404 page and redirect for the registering page with the sponsored nickname on it. I create a link:

http://mywebsite.net/John1
The 404 page will process the URL and catch the string John1 and assign to the field nickname in a way that the registering page should be such as:

Sponsor: John1

Name:__________________

E-mail: _______________

Etc.
Could someone help me on this hard task? At least some guidelines how to start would be much appreciated.

**My code in Rooter.php:**

```
$this->_response->setRedirect('customer/account/create');
$request->setDispatched(true);
$request->setParam('nickname', $request->getPathInfo());
return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect::class);
```

**My code in register.phtml:**

```
$sponsor = $block->getRequest()->getParam('nickname');
```

**$sponsor** returns null because **params:** array(0)

I can't figure out why.

Comment: You have to add your router to routerlist and using match function you can easily do this. Magento\Cms\Controller/Router this file help you.

Comment: I put the code $request->setParam('nickname', $request->getPathInfo()); to pass the parameter through phtml file, but somehow when I try to catch the parameter in my phtml file with $sponsor = $block->getRequest()->getParam('nickname'); $sponsor returns null.

Comment: have you checked the value of $request->getPathInfo() in router.php

Comment: Yes. It returns a value not null, namely ‘/John1’